# Add EMF form(view) in a RCP plugin

Tags: rcp, emf

I have followed this tutorial: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/getting-started-with-EMF-Forms
and now I am trying to embedd the EMF form I have createn(view) in a RCP plug-in.
I have created a simple RCP4 project and I have modified the SamplePart class as follows:

```
public class SamplePart {

    private EObject getDummyEObject() {
        final EClass eClass = MyPackage.eINSTANCE.getMyModelClass();
        return EcoreUtil.create(eClass);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
        final EObject dummyObject = getDummyEObject();
        try {
            final Composite content = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            content.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            content.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().margins(10, 10).create());
            content.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().create());
            ECPSWTViewRenderer.INSTANCE.render(content, dummyObject);
            content.layout();
        } catch (final ECPRendererException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        parent.layout();
    }   
}
```

This is the list of my dependencies:

```
javax.inject;bundle-version="1.0.0",
org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="[3.9.100,4.0.0)",
org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="[3.102.1,4.0.0)",
org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="[1.0.1,3.0.0)",
org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="[3.9.1,4.0.0)",
org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="[1.0.1,2.0.0)",
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="[1.0.2,2.0.0)",
org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="[1.3.0,2.0.0)",
org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",
org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="[1.3.1,2.0.0)",
org.eclipse.emf.ecore;bundle-version="[2.8.0,3.0.0)",
org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui.view.swt;bundle-version="[1.15.0,1.16.0)",
org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui.view;bundle-version="[1.15.0,1.16.0)",
org.eclipse.emf.ecp.edit;bundle-version="[1.15.0,1.16.0)",
com.myproject.ecore.mymodel;bundle-version="0.1.0",
org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.model.provider.xmi;bundle-version="1.15.0",
org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.model.provider.generator;bundle-version="1.15.0"
```

When I run the plug in I receive this error...any suggestion?
It works fine if I use the "make it happen:sample e4 application"

> org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: A null service reference is not allowed.
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1324)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4814)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:108)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4814)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:108)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:63)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:725)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:161)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: A null service reference is not allowed.
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:617)
>       at org.eclipse.emfforms.internal.core.services.controlmapper.ViewModelListener.(ViewModelListener.java:73)
>       at org.eclipse.emfforms.internal.core.services.controlmapper.SettingToControlMapperImpl.(SettingToControlMapperImpl.java:123)
>       at org.eclipse.emfforms.internal.core.services.controlmapper.SettingToControlMapFactoryImpl.createService(SettingToControlMapFactoryImpl.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.emfforms.internal.core.services.controlmapper.SettingToControlMapFactoryImpl.createService(SettingToControlMapFactoryImpl.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.emfforms.internal.core.services.scoped.EMFFormsViewServiceManagerImpl.getServiceOptional(EMFFormsViewServiceManagerImpl.java:100)
>       at org.eclipse.emfforms.internal.core.services.scoped.EMFFormsViewServiceManagerImpl.createGlobalImmediateService(EMFFormsViewServiceManagerImpl.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.internal.context.ViewModelContextImpl.loadImmediateServices(ViewModelContextImpl.java:320)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.internal.context.ViewModelContextImpl.instantiate(ViewModelContextImpl.java:277)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.internal.context.ViewModelContextImpl.(ViewModelContextImpl.java:171)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.spi.context.ViewModelContextFactory.createViewModelContext(ViewModelContextFactory.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.internal.swt.ECPSWTViewRendererImpl.render(ECPSWTViewRendererImpl.java:76)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.internal.swt.ECPSWTViewRendererImpl.render(ECPSWTViewRendererImpl.java:65)
>       at com.myproject.ecore.myplugin.parts.SamplePart.createComposite(SamplePart.java:32)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
>       ... 112 more

EDIT: I also have some messages like this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-03-19 10:46:54.715
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component 
org.eclipse.emfforms.swt.core.rendererfactory. The reference is: 
Reference[name = EMFFormsRendererService, interface = 
org.eclipse.emfforms.spi.swt.core.EMFFormsRendererService, policy = dynamic, 
cardinality = 0..n, target = null, bind = addEMFFormsRendererService, unbind = 
removeEMFFormsRendererService]
```

Comment: At a guess it doesn't like being in an e4 Part rather than a 3.x compatibility mode view.

Comment: But why the "make it happen:sample e4 application" works?It is a e4 Part

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `org.eclipse.emfforms.setup.base` and all required plug-ins to your launch configuration